# Kenitco Inline CSS

Tags: html, css, kentico

Not sure the best way to accomplish the following:

Currently we have header/billboard graphics setup to be background images to be used for a few templates. The issue is now allowing the user to change those background images in the Kentico CMS without having to update the CSS itself.

CSS

```
.billboard.landing-page {
    background-image: url("../img/billboard-sub-page.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 35.3125rem;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 4.0625rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 21.875rem; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper billboard landing-page">
<!-- Billboard Heading & Lead in -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-11 medium-9 columns">
    <div class="billboard-heading">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

What we're thinking will work is to remove the CSS call for the background image and add it as an inline style such as:

```
<div class="wrapper billboard landing-page" style="background-image:url(KENTICO-CODE-HERE);">
...
</div>
```

Does anyone have a good method to allow the user to select the image from the library and replace the URL in the inline style?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to not use static html.  You need to use page types and repeaters and make your page dynamic vs. just allowing the user to edit html and css.  [Check out the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+new+documents+and+pages) on adding content using page types (document types in v7).

Answer (score 2):

Like Brenden recommended, you need to add Background field to your page type, so editor will populate that field on the form tab. In this case you could use macro to inject Background field value into markup like this:

```
<div class="wrapper billboard landing-page" style="background-image:url({%Background%});">
...
</div>
```

Comment: What's the best steps / documentation / tutorial to do this? Thank you for your answer - Kentico is a new system for us

Comment: 1. Go to Page (Document) Types; 2. Navigate appropriate page type; 3. Click edit page type; 4. Go to Fields tab; 5. Add new text field named BackgroundImage; 6. Go to Pages application and navigate any page of that page type in the CMS Tree; 7. Open Form tab for that page; 8. Populate BackgroundImage field; 9. Add HTML from my answer to your page

Comment: The user interaction should be such that they select an image from the media library and the URL of that image is replaced in the inline style. Walking through your steps now, thank you. I assume instead of a text field, make it an image select field. Also - The HTML for these page would reside in the Page Template, so I replace the inline style with the macro you provided?

Comment: Yes, image selector would work better in your case and yes, put macro in your template.

Comment: Not sure if I've missed a step, but the output is still just showing the actual macro ```style="background-image:url({%BackgroundImage%});"```

Comment: Is it possible to place that markup along with macro into some web part? e.g. Static HTML.

Comment: I think, ideally; that would be the process. We have specific design elements (modules) that SHOULD be web parts that the user can drag into a WebPart Zone. I'll see if that works (stil learning Kentico)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which approach you would like to go (use macros, custom macro, web parts..). If you are using Portal engine I would actually recommend to create a web part for your billboard image along with a custom field using **media selection** form control to select image from media library.

Steps to do this:

1) Go to Page types (Document types for Kentico 7) application and create a new field using "Media selection" form control. Use e.g. **MediaImage** as field name.

2) Create a web part according to [this documentation article](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Creating+new+web+parts)

3) Use following code to get url of your **MediaImage** field and construct the HTML code:

```
        var mediaImage = CurrentDocument.GetStringValue("MediaImage", null); // image from custom field using "MediaSelection" form control
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaImage))
        {
            // continue only if image is set
            var url = URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(mediaImage);
            var html = String.Format("<div class=\"wrapper billboard landing - page\" style=\"background - image:url({0}); \">", url);
        }
```

4) Add this HTML to a page using e.g. Literal control

5) Place your web part on a page where you want to have this image (I suppose it would be master page or some other page from which child pages inherit)

Comment: There is no reason for a custom webpart Richard.  This can be handled with a page type and an out of the box repeater with a transformation with no custom code.

Comment: Yeah, that surely is possible. You can also use macros to generate the same code as well. Having a simple web part for this might be easier for some users to use. Depending on scenario you could also incorporate some properties for e.g. default image, width, size and others which might be easer to handle from properties instead of transformation.